# How to create a stun, turn and signaling server

Tags: html5-video, webrtc, stun, turn, signaling

Is there a simple guide from where I can start creating a `stun / turn and signaling server` ?

I spend over a week searching for those things and couldn't find any guide where I can say:

*okay, I am on the right track now - this is clear.*

So far, everything is so abstract without any examples.

This is what I'm trying to [achieve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46635558/video-and-audio-stream-server-to-clients-only): a simple video stream on my local network where I'll have a server with installed usb camera on it, and an application on my *iis* which will connect to the usb camera and stream it to the clients, and every time when a client opens the application, will see the video stream from the server camera.

*Note: since I want to use it on my local network do I really need a stun/turn server, or is there a guide that shows how to avoid it ?*

Answer (score 0):

Media streamed over dedicated servers HTTP/HTTPS rarely needs a NAT traversal solution. Instead, just have your web server with camera attached, on the public Internet or behind your NAT with port-forwarding enabled.

There are LOTS of streaming media solutions available as open source, free downloads, or commercially sold.  A good list is here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_streaming_media_systems